# High memory usage on Arch Linux based distro

Tags: linux, memory, arch-linux, memory-leaks

Every so often, i notice my computer starts to become slow, and then before i know it, completely unusable. I (barely) open bashtop/htop to see whats going on and i see that (example) 59GB/62.8GB of my memory is being used and i can't see any programs that are using that much memory. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZhkw.png) that i managed to capture

### The programs that i was running before the crash happened now were:

- Minecraft Fabric 1.18.2 Java edition  with Sodium installed, through MultiMC
- ssh
- Brave (brave-nightly-bin)
- Thunar file manager

### My system specifications:

- OS: Archcraft x86-64
- Motherboard: B450 AORUS ELITE
- Kernel: 5.18.1-arch1-1
- Window manager: dwm
- Display manager: ly
- Compositor: picom
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X (12) @ 3.600GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
- RAM: 2 x TridentZ Neo DDR4 16GB & 2 x HyperX Fury 16GB

Sometimes its so bad that I can't even open bashtop/htop to get a screenshot or to look at whats going on, and even if i manage to open one of these 2, the navigation through them is very slow if not impossible. Even through the TTY.

The current way I fix this is by rebooting my PC.

I'm not sure how to debug this after rebooting. It's very hard to use the PC without rebooting to fix the issue, I would appreciate it if someone could help me find some logs or something that could be helpful for troubleshooting this issue, or if someone already knows how to fix it

Comment: Try to get memory usage from `systemd-cgtop` and from `slabtop`. I'll guess it's a memory leak in the nvidia GPU driver, though.

Comment: There are types of memory allocation in Linux that are not attributed to processes, mostly with drivers. Check user1686's comment on that. Also check for large *tmpfs* instances and third-party kernel modules (like ZFS).

Comment: @user1686 I'll keep these 2 tools running on the side and look at them if the issue happens again, is that ok? Also, I've been running the NVIDIA driver version 515.43.04, I can try updating to 515.48.07